# How to set Phinx migrations to create migration class with up/down method

Tags: php, database-migration, phinx

Can you tell me please if is possible to set Phinx migrations to create migration class with up/down method instead of change which is default option? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can create your own [migration template](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/commands.html#the-create-command) and provide it from command line, but I don't know if there is any `sh phinx create Migration --up-down` thing.

Comment: Yes I have it. But it is not exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: If somebody don't know, template you can set class name via $className in template file. Also save template as txt file to alove this.

Answer (score 1):

Create your [own migration template](https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/blob/master/src/Phinx/Migration/Migration.template.php.dist):

```
<?php

use $useClassName;

class $className extends $baseClassName
{
    public function up() {

    }

    public function down() {

    }
}
```

And then apply it in the config:

```
paths:
    migrations:
        - application/module1/migrations
templates:
    file: <your-custom-tmplate.path>
```